# Javascript - Focus on element after closing Modal

Tags: javascript, focus, bootstrap-modal, autofocus

I have a button with the autofocus atribute.
When the user clicks on the button (or presses the "enter key", since it has autofocus), a modal pops up.
That modal has an input field with the autofocus attribute as well.
After the user types something there and presses the "enter key", the modal will be closed.

I would like to have the initial button focused again, after closing the modal.
But I cannot make it work.

I tried both adding the `autofocus` attribute to the button itself and I also tried adding `document.getElementById("myBtn").focus();` to the function that closes the modal. None worked.

I tried replacing the input field for a button to close the modal and it works that way, so I guess the problema has something to do with the `onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) closeModal();` in the input, since the "enter key" is used for more than one thing in the page.

Are my assumptions right? Is there a way to make it work in these conditions?

Here's a simplified version of what I am working with:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("modalInput").focus();
}

function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myBtn").focus();
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" autofocus>Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>This is a modal.</p>
    <input id="modalInput" type="text" autofocus onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) closeModal();">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using button can't we use anchor tag?https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_blur

Comment: @Vikram Thakur, I would rather not. It would mess with the overall design of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing on the button is called simultaneously while you pressing the enter key with the input tag. That triggers immediate enter key event on the button.

So that the modal seems not closing. Putting `setTimeout` will fix it. You may need to style it by using the `:focus` psedo-class selector to show it like focused.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("modalInput").focus();
}

function closeModal() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      document.getElementById("myBtn").focus();
    },0)
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" autofocus>Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>This is a modal.</p>
    <input id="modalInput" type="text" autofocus onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) closeModal();">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help you :)